# Make AWS API Gateway accessible only as SNS subscription endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sns

On my current project we configured forwarding of Cloudwatch alarms to Slack channel. For that we use AWS SNS topic + API Gateway which is subscribed on that topic and forwarded alarms to Slack webhook.

The issue I'm trying to solve - currently the REST resource of the mentioned API Gateway is public (it don't require any auth and is available from Internet). How can I configure API Gateway that it could be available only as SNS subscription endpoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the API gateway with the Endpoint type : **Private**

And you need to create a VPC end point for SNS to access the end point internally. 
More Info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-vpc-endpoint-policies.html